# HOC vs cloneElement in 2019

Tags: reactjs

I learned that you could use HOC to only modify the render function when the class logic is the same. I try to do it myself and came up with a solution using this.props.children and cloneElement instead.

I searched on StackOverFlow to find differences between the 2 but the only question about this is from 2016 and React changed since. I was wondering if there is performance issues with one or the other and in 2019 what would be considered "best practice"

Here's with cloneElement:

```
 <Counter>
  <ButtonCounter />
</Counter>
<Counter>
  <KeyStrokesCounter />
</Counter>
```

```
export default class Counter extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            counter: 0
        };
    }

    updateCounter = () => {
        this.setState(prev => ({
            counter: prev.counter + 1
        }));
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
                    clickHandler: this.updateCounter,
                    counter: this.state.counter
                })}
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

```
export default class ButtonCounter extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log('ButtonCounter created lol');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.props.clickHandler}>
                    Clicked {this.props.counter} times
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And HOC:

```
<Button />
<InputKeyStroke />
```

```
const CounterComponent = OgComp => {
    class NewComp extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                counter: 42
            };
        }

        incrementCounter = () => {
            this.setState(prev => ({
                counter: prev.counter + 1
            }));
        };

        render() {
            return (
                <OgComp
                    evtHandler={this.incrementCounter}
                    counter={this.state.counter}
                />
            );
        }
    }

    return NewComp;
};

export default CounterComponent;
```

```
export default CounterComponent(
    class Button extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            console.log('RCONST BUTTON');
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <button onClick={this.props.evtHandler}>
                    Clicked {this.props.counter} times
                </button>
            );
        }
    }
);
```

Is there a best way to do this? The constructor isn't called during each cloneElement event.

Comment: In 2019 you even can use hooks

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question but here's a benchmark I found for cloneElement VS render props: https://gist.github.com/nemoDreamer/21412b28dc65d51e2c5c8561a8f82ce1